# Auto layout: how to set the hugging & resistance priority for two multi-line UILabel stacked vertically?

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, autolayout

I've already implement a custom cell using auto layout like this:

[image]

It has 4 parts as you can see: `[thumbnail, title, summary, feedName]`.

I need to layout `title` & `summary` beautifully. They're both multi-line UILabels.

What I need to achieve is that when there are too many texts, the summary's line count gets decreased first, then the title's, not like what the picture is showing (the title only occupies one line).

I've tried setting the hugging and resistance priorities like this, but it's not working, any ideas?

**title**:

[image]

**summary**:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems I need to **always** set the **preferredMaxLayoutWidth** for a multi-line label, even its width can be calculated by constraints to surrounding views.

By setting this, it's working perfectly now.

```
self.titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = maxLayoutWidth;
self.summaryLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = maxLayoutWidth;
```

[image]